# yii2 + join query in ActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-user

This is my actual query -

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => UserProfile::find()->with(['user'])
        ]);
```

'**status**' field is exist in user table. So I want to filter data by where **status != 0** but it fails.

I tried this -

1

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => UserProfile::find()->with(['user'])->where('user.status !=',0)
        ]);
```

2

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => UserProfile::find()->with(['user'])->where('<>','user.status',0)
        ]);
```

None of it works. please let me how its possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need change your `$dataProvider` code with this code.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => UserProfile::find()->joinWith(['user(relation_name)'])->where(['<>','user.status',0])
        ]);
```

Comment: I have add array in `where` function.

Comment: I got this error - 

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.status' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user_profile` WHERE `user`.`status` <> 0

Comment: in `with()` `user` is relation name?

Comment: Yes. UserProfile has relation with User. like this - user_profile.user_id = user.id